# Would this wiring question be appropriate on EE.SE?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

We have a [question on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12166/electric-wires) that is off topic there. It deals with electrical wiring, which from what I've heard is not necessarily considered electrical engineering, but I wanted to check whether such things fall under the scope of this site. If the question would be appropriate here I'd like to migrate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds more like home improvements to me TBH.

Comment: Hmm... yeah, I could see that. I'll wait to see if anyone else has something to add here, but I'll also ask the DIY people if they want it.

Comment: @David - I'm with Matt on this one.  The [electrical tag on Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical) is a good fit for questions like this.